# DataGridView with Custom Object List throws NotImplementedException when Editing

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, datagridview

I am building a WinForms application with a few custom business objects. I bind a List of a single type of object to a DataGridView with BindingList and implement IEditableObject on my object, but when I attempt to edit the values in the DataGridView I get the following exception:

---

The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
>   - at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component,Object value)
>   - at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.PushValue(Int32 boundColumnIndex, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
>
> To replace this default dialog, please handle the DataError event.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently I'm not very observant...

The problem was that ReSharper implemented my properties with NotImplementedException, so when I edited that property through the DataGridView, it threw that Exception.

Thanks, sorry to waste your (and my!) time.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you all you need to know - you need to handle the [`DataError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror.aspx) event of your `DataGridView`.

The MSDN page I linked above also links to an article on [Consuming Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ccyd347.aspx) that may be helpful as well:

> To consume an event in an application,
>   you must provide an event handler (an
>   event-handling method) that executes
>   program logic in response to the event
>   and register the event handler with
>   the event source. This process is
>   referred to as event wiring. The
>   visual designers for Windows Forms and
>   Web Forms provide rapid application
>   development (RAD) tools that simplify
>   or hide the details of event wiring.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have been more clear. I am trying to figure out what is causing the error. I understand that handling the error can be customized, but I don't know why I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had an exception with a list of custom objects with 'Index - 1':

```
List<Object> newObjList = new List<Object>();
```

OR

```
IList<Object> newObjList = new List<Object>();
```

Was assigning the quick and dirty way:

```
dgv.DataSource = null                      //this is user preferred way to refresh list
dgv.DataSource = newObjList
```

Resolved this by casting the datasource assignment to an array:

```
dgv.DataSource = newObject.ToArray<Object>();
```